# How to compare TargetRowCount in Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm not from SQL background so I'll need a very clear answer. On daily basis I'm building interfaces in .net and sometimes pulling data from SQL using simple statements. I never had anything to do with the store procedures before. Both our developer(away on monthly vacation) and our DBA(who is sick for unforeseeable future) are away and being the only person left who at least saw SQL Server I ended up replacing both of them. I feel very much out of my depth and there is no one in my office to ask. My boss who used to be a SQL developer before he became boss and stopped doing technical things insisted today that there is a problem with this stored procedure and that I am to fix it. I truly have no idea how. C# is so much easier...

This (apparently faulty) stored procedure was designed to populate a new field - Sequence. It was meant to take a ClientID, and then update the User records for that ClientID. If the number of updated records varies from the expected number of updates, the transaction is supposed to rollback.

My boss claims that this procedure is written wrong. Could you please help and correct it for me so that I can use it with my limited SQL knowledge?

```
DECLARE @TargetRowCount INT

SELECT @TargetRowCount = COUNT(*)  
FROM dbo.Users  
WHERE ClientId = @ClientId  
            AND Sequence <> UPPER(Name)
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE dbo.Users
SET Sequence = UPPER(Name)


SELECT COUNT(*)  
FROM dbo.Users  
WHERE ClientId = @ClientId  
            AND Sequence <> UPPER(Name)

IF(@@RowCount <> @TargetRowCount)  
            ROLLBACK TRAN  
ELSE  
            COMMIT TRAN
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should first put `BEGIN TRAN` in the right position (that is, before actually updating)

Comment: Maybe. I don't understand your logic though. After the update there should be zero rows where `Sequence <> UPPER(Name)`

Comment: I'm not a SQL person so I don't understand what the logic behind stored procedures should be:( Can you help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a hard time to understad the purpose of that script but anyway. 
see the comments i included. hopefully it'll help you:

```
DECLARE @TargetRowCount INT;
DECLARE @ChckRC1 INT;
DECLARE @ChckRC2 INT;

-- select how many rows with wrong name exist    
SELECT @TargetRowCount = COUNT(*)  
FROM dbo.Users  
WHERE ClientId = @ClientId  
  AND Sequence <> UPPER(Name)

BEGIN TRAN

-- update users sequence, but really all? 
UPDATE dbo.Users
SET Sequence = UPPER(Name)
-- i'd add the where clause from above
WHERE ClientId = @ClientId  
  AND Sequence <> UPPER(Name);

-- store how many rows the update hit
SET @ChckRC1 = @@ROWCOUNT;

-- select again how many rows with wrong name exist    
SELECT @ChckRC2 = COUNT(*)  
FROM dbo.Users  
WHERE ClientId = @ClientId  
  AND Sequence <> UPPER(Name);

-- first count is different than actually updated rows, 
-- some disappeared or new appeared. 
IF (@ChckRC1 <> @TargetRowCount ) 
-- second count should be zero
-- any other value suggest, there is still a user with wrong sequence
OR (@ChckRC2 <> 0 )
            ROLLBACK TRAN  
ELSE  
            COMMIT TRAN
```

i have no idea why you are checking the counts 3 times. what i'd do is:

```
-- update users sequence of some client with wrong sequence
UPDATE dbo.Users
SET Sequence = UPPER(Name)
WHERE ClientId = @ClientId  
  AND Sequence <> UPPER(Name);

return @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Comment: I understand your query, but after updating, there shouldn't be any rows with the wrong name, and if they are, they should be new rows. So, what would be the point on rolling back if the result doesn't match?, there should almost never match